# if two vectors are linearly dependent, one of them is a scalar multiple of the other.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that if two vectors are linearly dependent, one of them is a scalar multiple of the other?

Comment: maybe for the next time you could show some of your work or at least say why you couldn't solve/prove on your own...

Answer (score 7):

If $v,w$ are linearly dependent so there is constants $c_1,c_2$ which both are not zero at the same time and $c_1v+c_2w=0$. Let $c_1\neq 0$ so by dividing, we have $v=\frac{-c_2}{c_1}w$.